# Most likely color space for scanner?

Tags: srgb, scanner

I have a scanner from 2010 (Canoscan 8800F) which does not include color profiling software. I figure it is using a 'canned' profile, as is mentioned [here](http://www.colourphil.co.uk/scanner-camera-profiling.shtml). It scans images to tif files without embedding an ICC color profile. When I read in the RGB values from the tif file, what color space should I assume the RGB values are in? I am thinking sRGB was most common in 2010, but would welcome any thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try importing it, using various likely RGB color spaces, and see what seems to be best. It may not be sRGB, but how many other likely values would make sense?

It's pricey, German after-market software, but if you want good calibration for this scanner, you might want to try using the Silverfast driver: http://www.silverfast.com/product/Canon/CanoScan-8800F-688/en.html

Comment: I used to use their software, years ago, with a Nikon slide scanner, and it definitely improved scan quality. I purchased the software with an IT-8 target, so calibration was part of the process.

Comment: That is a good suggestion along with the IT-8 target.